# Sitecore 8.1 update 2 MongoDB backup

Tags: mongodb, sitecore

I am using replica set (2 mongo, 1 arbitor) for my Sitecore CD servers.
Assuming all mongo DB data get flushed to Reporting SQL DB; do we need to take backup of MongoDB database on production CD ?
If yes what is best approach and frequency to do it; considering My application is moderately using anaytics feature (Personalization , Campaign etc).

Comment: Did you know there was a Sitecore-specific StackExchange site? Head over to https://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your assumption is bad - the MongoDB is the definitive source of analytic data, not the reporting db.  The reporting db contains only the aggregate info needed for generating the report (mostly).  In fact, if (when) something goes wrong with the SQL DB, the idea is that it is rebuilt from the source MongoDB.  Remember: *You can't un-add two numbers after you've added them!*

**Backup vs Replication**
A backup is a point-in-time view of the database, where replication is multiple active copies of a current database.  I would advocate for replication over backup for this type of data. Why? Glad you asked!

- Currency - under what circumstance would you want to restore a 50GB MongoDB? What if it was a week old? What if it was a month? Really the only useful data is current data, and websites are volatile places - log data backups are out of date within an hour.  If you personalise on stale data is that providing a good user experience?
- Cost - backing up large datasets is costly in terms of time, storage capacity and compute requirements; they are also a pain to restore and the bigger they are the more likely there's a corruption somewhere

***Run of business***

In a production MongoDB environment you **really should have 2-3 replicas**. That's going to save your arse if one of the boxes dies, which they sometimes do - MongoDB works the disks very hard.

These replicas are self-healing, and always current (pretty-much) so they are much better than taking backups.  The chances that you lose *all* your replicas at once is really low except for one particular edge case... upgrades.  So a backup is really only protection against hardware failure or data corruption which, in a multi-instance replica set, is already very effectively handled.  Unless you're paranoid, you're never going to use that backup and it'll cost you plenty to have it.

***Sitecore Upgrades***

This is the killer edge-case - always make backups (see [Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)) before running an upgrade because you can corrupt all of your replicas in one motion and you'll want to be able to roll back.

**Data Trimming (side-note)**

You didn't ask this, but at some point you'll be thinking "how the heck can I back up this 170GB monster db every day? this is ridiculous" - and you'll be right.

There are various schools of thought around how long this data should be persisted for - that's a question only you or your client can answer. I suggest keeping it until there's too much, then make a decision on how much you have to get rid of.  Keep as much as you can tolerate.

Comment: Thanks Richard Hauer for detail info. What I got is MongoDB backup must be taken as it acts as a source for analytics data. Having considered that I have backup plan for SQL Analytics/Reporting db; and our application is not capturing much analytics data as per design. In this scenarios also I have to take backup of MongoDB; if yes what should be the ideal frequency I should maintain as we are taking daily backup for SQL dbs.

Comment: @FaiyazulHaqueNoor - I suggest you read that through again. tl;dr you only need a backup when running upgrades; for production you should have replicas instead.